# Переход на страницу приложения в Play Market по нажатию кнопки

Tags: google-play, android

У меня есть кнопка, мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на неё переходило на страницу приложения в Play Market, а если у пользователя не установлен Play Market, то чтобы заходило в Play Market через браузер. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: @Sting95, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070

Comment: в гугле находится за 6 секунд. Стыдно @Sting95, стыдно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/4579593)

Comment: да, в комментариях эту ссылку уже дали

Comment: Не заметил сразу... ну так все равно виднее будет :)